# Is there a way to send some arguments through the instruments command-line where UI Automation script could access them?

Tags: xcode, command-line-arguments, instruments, ui-automation

I'm trying to send some arguments to UI Automation scripts through the command-line where the scripts could grab those arguments and execute some specific test cases conditionally based on those received arguments. Is there a way to do this? I saw in the manual page for the instruments command that it mentioned something about arguments.

> argument
>        ~ Command line argument to be sent to the launched process (You may specify more than one)

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/instruments.1.html

... Or should I just split the conditional code into different files and have some external shell scripts to handle changing of the file name to be executed through the instruments command-line instead?

Comment: doesn't -- argument as mentioned in the documentation -- work-- ??https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/instruments.1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alas, not at this time. The command line arguments get sent to the application itself (which is the launched process), but the automation script has no access to any command line arguments or even environment variables for that matter. Please file a [bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com) with Apple about this. The more they hear about it, the higher on their priority list it will go.

Your suggestion to have a shell script execute different automation scripts is what I do and it works well.

Comment: Further reading from March 2014: http://cocoamanifest.net/articles/2014/03/ui-screen-shooter-now-simpler-and-more-robust-since-xcode-5-1.html

Comment: @Jonathan Penn Any luck with the new versions ??

Answer (score 8):

My workaround on this problem uses an exported environment variable and the `UIATarget.localTarget().host().performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout(...)` command to acquire that parameter.

1. Export an environment variable in the shell

   `export PARAM_TO_UIA="theParameterValue"`
2. Launch instruments from the same shell
3. Acquire the parameter inside your UIAutomation script

   `var result = target.host().performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout("/usr/bin/printenv" , ["PARAM_TO_UIA"], 5);`

   `var parameter = result.stdout.substring(0,result.stdout.length-1);`

Last command removes '\n' from the end of the `result.stdout` string.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround:

I have a shell script append the variables to a second JavaScript file. This file can then be imported in your original JavaScript file that is used for instruments. In this case you can use any external variables in your JavaScript file that instructs the mobile app.

I have an example of my script below:
https://github.com/jeroen1985/iOS-screenshots-automation-Bash

Let me know if you have any questions.

Thank you,

Jeroen